# Replace Non exact Needle in Haystack

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a Javascript function that replaces needle's in a haystack as you will see the haystack is the entire body of the page.

```
function replace(needle, replacement) {
    haystackText = document.body.innerHTML
    var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
    var replaced = "";
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
    document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

My problem is that the needles im looking for are not exact. For examples sake ill say the needle text is "foo". The text i would want to replace might then look like this.

```
Here is some example text abcfooxyz, that is all.
```

I need to replace abcfooxyz, but all i know what to look for is foo. So if the replacement text was bar i need the output to look like this.

```
Here is some example text bar that is all.
```

I'm sorry if this is obvious i have searched for a solution but javascript is not my native language however im forced to use it for the implementation of this app. I can use jQuery but i would prefer not to as i have not yet called the library and i do not know it well.

Thank you for your assistance.

**EDIT: Solution Found**

Ok so after some additional reading and experimentation with RegExp i have written a separate function to deal with URL's in side a a href html tag. This is used to redirect users who click outbound links to a warning page before continuing and stopping refferal and page rank data flow with rel="noreferrer". Here bdy is the java script documnet.body.innerHTML element.

```
function linkreplace(link, bdy) {
    haystackText = bdy;
    var replacement = 'a href=\"http://mysite.com/outbound_refer.php?link=' + link + '\" rel=\"noreferrer\"';
    var match = new RegExp('[^\\<\\>]*' + link + '[^\\>\\<]*', 'ig');
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
    return replaced;
}
```

Here RegExp finds the needle text and includes all text within the HTML Tag until it find the tag open and close. Here \< and \> set the expression to look for special characters of < and > so <> in regular text wont match. The ^ sets the Expression to match all characters except for the ones in the brackets.

Comment: You'll need an exact specification as to what "non-exact" means.  Does it mean you want to replace any word that contains your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var match = new RegExp('(\\b)\\w*' + needle + '\\w*(\\b)', 'ig');
haystackText.replace(match, '$1' + replacement + '$2');
```

Explanation of regex:

```
\b        word boundary (space, punctuation, etc)
\w*       0 or more alphanumeric characters
[needle]  your text
\w*       0 or more alphanumeric characters
\b        word boundary
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I've made an error.  If you use this code, it will also replace the word boundaries with your replacement text.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Does RegExp have anyway of excluding characters like /\& etc... as foo could be in a url such as http://www.blahfooblah.com/dir/ok.php?a=1&b=2 in this case the entire URL should be replaced with bar. The only object that should cause the needle replacement to end should be a space.

Comment: In short my problem is that a space needs to count as a word boundary but punctuation like /\&: cant. I see no way around this as javascript views punctuation as a word boundary.

Comment: You could modify your regex, then.  Change `\b` to `\s` and `\w` to `\S`

Comment: essentially im trying to turn `blah <a href="http://foo.com/">This is spam</a> blah` into `blah bar blah` im having trouble defining `<` and `>` in the expression.

Comment: Using regex to parse/manipulate HTML is not recommended.  You'll run across many difficulties doing so.  It might be easier for you to use Regex just for the text replacement and something like jQuery to inspect your HTML elements and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The following will match "foo" surrounded by any number of alphanumeric characters, including zero.

```
\w*foo\w*
```